# Use USB port of raspi from ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, usb

I am trying to export a USB port over IP from raspi and use it on ubuntu.

On the raspberry pi I can start the daemon using

```
> sudo usbipd
usbipd: info: starting usbipd (usbip-utils 2.0)
usbipd: info: listening on 0.0.0.0:3240
usbipd: info: listening on :::3240
```

As you see the version is reported as 2.0. I was also able to bind a device to usbip and list devices from the raspi using:

```
> sudo usbip list -r localhost
Exportable USB devices
======================
 - localhost
      1-1.4: Logitech, Inc. : Mouseman Dual Optical (046d:c012)
           : /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
           : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
```

On ubuntu I installed usbip over apt-get install usbip.
The version is reported as 0.1.7-3.

When I try to list the devices on my server I get this:

```
> sudo usbip -l 192.168.0.126
- 192.168.0.126
usbip err: usbip_network.c: 119 (usbip_recv_op_common) recv op_common, -1
usbip err: vhci_attach.c: 202 (query_exported_devices) recv op_common
usbip err: vhci_attach.c: 417 (show_exported_devices) query
```

The output is quite cryptical but I think the problem is that usbip 2 can not talk to usb ip 0.1.7-3.

So what can I do there? Can I setup it in some way so it is compatible?
Can I install the usbip 2 version on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

update client Tools solve this Error:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic
```

This will install newer usbip tools into /usr/lib/linux-tools/`uname -r`

```
$ /usr/lib/linux-tools/`uname -r`/usbip version
```

or

```
$ /usr/lib/linux-tools/4.4.0-31-generic/usbip version
```

usbip (usbip-utils 2.0)

**New Syntax, e.g:**
usbip list -r 192.168.1.1
sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.1.1 -b 1-1.3

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet.
Have you seen this [post](http://sourceforge.net/p/usbip/discussion/418508/thread/ba6d95b2/?limit=25)? It seems to deal with the same problem that comes from a version mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to confirm that the versions are incompatible. I hope someone knows how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should download kernel sources for your kernel and build usbip tools included in tools/usb/usbip/. Detailed HOWTO here: https://blog.danman.eu/usbip-utils-2-0-on-ubuntu/

Comment: This is a **link only answer** and is discouraged on AskUbuntu. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/734969/edit) your answer to include a description of the steps in your link to improve your post.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete for newer releases of Ubuntu. usbip-tools modules and binaries are now included in the `linux-tools-generic` package.